# Mouseleave not working as expected on hover

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items in the "a href" tag here:

```
<a href="#something" class="list-item">
    <div>Title</div>
    <div>Subtitle</div>
</a>
<div class="description hide">
    This text description is hidden on default
</div>

<a href="#somethingelse" class="list-item">
    <div>Title</div>
    <div>Subtitle</div>
</a>
<div class="description hide">
    This text description is hidden on default
</div>

<a href="#anotherlink" class="list-item">
    <div>Title</div>
    <div>Subtitle</div>
</a>
<div class="description hide">
    This text description is hidden on default
</div>

...


<div id="area-for-descriptions">

    <!-- Here the descriptions will be detached and appended on mouse on and and on mouse off they will return back where they were in the beginning -->

</div>
```

---

my css:

```
.hide { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

---

my current jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('mouseenter', 'a.list-item', function() {
            var currentItem = $( this ).next(); 
            currentItem.detach().appendTo('#area-for-descriptions');
            currentItem.removeClass('hide');
            currentItem.addClass('show');
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', 'a.list-item', function() {
        var currentItem = $( this );
        $('#area-for-descriptions a.list-item').detach().appendTo(currentItem);
    });

});
```

---

But only the mouseenter is working. Mouseleave is not working and it messes my code.

Any idea how to alter my current code, so the mouseleave is working too?

I need to get the description back where it was and give it hide class so it's hidden and on the same position in the html code as in the beginning (before hovering over the item)

Comment: There's no need to `detach()` before using `appendTo()`

Comment: The problem is that I want to cut the item within the #area-for-descriptions the and put it back on the same place below the a href of the item as it was in the beginning (before the mouseenter event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to move the element, just clone it on mouseenter and put that in `#area-for-descriptions` and empty `#area-for-descriptions` on mouseleave.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('mouseenter', 'a.list-item', function() {
        $( this ).next().clone().removeClass('hide').appendTo('#area-for-descriptions');
    }).on('mouseleave', 'a.list-item', function() {
        $('#area-for-descriptions').empty();
    });

});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1cL6237d/1/)

By the way, there's no need to `detach()` before using `appendTo()`.

Comment: Thank you, the Demo is working, but my I cannot make it work in my code for some reason. Hmm. But thanks anyway.

Comment: For some reason I had to add `$('#area-for-descriptions .category-description').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');` after `$( this ).next().clone().show().appendTo('#area-for-descriptions');` and it's finally working ;)

Comment: Ok. `.show()` should overridden the `display: none` in your `.hide` class. You shouldn't need `addClass('show')` because `display: block` is default for a `<div>`

Comment: Also `$('#area-for-descriptions .category-description')` **is** the clone, so you don't need to search for it. Just chain those commands to the clone. `$( this ).next().clone().appendTo('#area-for-descriptions').removeClass('hide');` I've updated the answer.